# Remove attributes from a JSON string before deserializing

Tags: regex, json, .net-2.0

The web service I'm calling returns a JSON response with much more data than I actually need to use and it's causing the deserialization process to take a very long time.

I'm using VB.NET and the Newtonsoft JSON library.

Using the following JSON as an example, how can I remove all values except the 'id' value?

```
{"results": [
  {"id":"1234", "name":"name value", "logo":"<some base64 encoded string>"},
  {"id":"1234", "name":"name value", "logo":"<some base64 encoded string>"},
  {"id":"1234", "name":"name value", "logo":"<some base64 encoded string>"},
  {"id":"1234", "name":"name value", "logo":"<some base64 encoded string>"},
  {"id":"1234", "name":"name value", "logo":"<some base64 encoded string>"}
]}
```

Would regular expressions be the best way?

I have just learnt that it also needs to handle a nested array of objects that also have an `id` property.  The nested `id` property should be excluded from the final JSON.

```
{"results": [
  {"id":"1234", "name":"name value", "categories":[{"id":"1","name":"category"}]},
  {"id":"1234", "name":"name value", "categories":[{"id":"1","name":"category"}]},
  {"id":"1234", "name":"name value", "categories":[{"id":"1","name":"category"}]},
  {"id":"1234", "name":"name value", "categories":[{"id":"1","name":"category"}]},
  {"id":"1234", "name":"name value", "categories":[{"id":"1","name":"category"}]}
]}
```

Comment: No, regex is probably not a solution, it won't be able to parse JSON or properly remove something. Instead, go find some parser you can hook on or which allows lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following expression

```
(?<="id":")[0-9]*(?=")
```

to get the IDs and then build your JSON string by using a `for` / `foreach` loop and a `StringBuilder`.

I'll post a sample usage using C#, maybe you could adapt it for VB:

```
var json = "{\"results\": [" +
"{\"id\":\"1234\", \"name\":\"name value\", \"logo\":\"<some base64 encoded string>\"}," +
"{\"id\":\"1234\", \"name\":\"name value\", \"logo\":\"<some base64 encoded string>\"}," +
"{\"id\":\"1234\", \"name\":\"name value\", \"logo\":\"<some base64 encoded string>\"}," +
"{\"id\":\"1234\", \"name\":\"name value\", \"logo\":\"<some base64 encoded string>\"}," +
"{\"id\":\"1234\", \"name\":\"name value\", \"logo\":\"<some base64 encoded string>\"}" +
"]}";

//try to get matches when JSON contains categories
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(json, "(?<=\"id\":\")[0-9]*(?=\", \"name\":\".*\", \"categories\")");

//if no matches are present (i.e. categories are not included in the JSON)
if(matches.Count==0)
    matches = Regex.Matches(json, "(?<=\"id\":\")[0-9]*(?=\")");

StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
sBuilder.Append("{\"results\": [");

for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
{
    sBuilder.Append("{\"id\":\"");
    sBuilder.Append(matches[i].Value);
    if (i == matches.Count - 1)
        break;
    sBuilder.Append("\"},");
}

sBuilder.Append("\"}]}");

//use the JSON string
//sBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: This looks like a nice solution.  Would it support the other sample JSON I just added?  I suspect I'd need to use a Regex to remove the "categories" array before using your existing code.

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987) JSON is not a regular language so using regex is not the best way to achieve your goal (although maybe it can be done). It is much better to use your parser for that kind of manipulations.

I think that with JSON.NET, for selecting items, you can do something like:

```
var ids = response["results"].Children()["id"]
```